# setting value using address.call() doesn't works

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging, abi.encodewithsignature, address.call

I am trying to run a setter function (testCallBar) in Caller contract which should run setVal() of Receiver contract using call method. But it does not works. testCallFoo() works as expected but testCallBar() always returns false.

*What I want to achieve is to run any function of Receiver contract from Caller contract using call() method.*

What am I doing wrong here? Also, what is the better way to run any function with any datatype arguments to run using address.call() method in such scenarios?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Receiver {
    event Received(address caller, uint256 amount, string message);
    
    uint256 bar = 9;

    function foo(string memory _message, uint _x) public payable returns (uint256) {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value, _message);
        return _x + 1;
    }
    
    function getVal() public view returns(uint256) {
        return bar;
    }
    
    function setVal(uint256 _bar) public payable returns (uint256) {
        bar = _bar;
        return bar;
    }
    
}

contract Caller {
    event Response(bool success, bytes data);

    // Let's imagine that contract B does not have the source code for
    // contract A, but we do know the address of A and the function to call.
    function testCallFoo(address payable _addr, uint256 z) public payable {
        // You can send ether and specify a custom gas amount
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _addr.call{value: msg.value, gas: 5000}(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("foo(string,uint256)", "call foo", z)
        );

        emit Response(success, data);
    }
    
    function testCallBar(address payable _addr, uint256 z) public payable {
        // You can send ether and specify a custom gas amount
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _addr.call{value: msg.value, gas: 5000}(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("setVal(uint256)", z)
        );

        emit Response(success, data);
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the allocated gas from 5000 to 10000 in the call inside the `testCallBar` function and it will work.

In fact, `setVal` is more expensive than `foo` as it updates a state variable (`bar`).

Comment: It was so simple..lol. Thank you @clement